# evaluating an array as the field of a class?

Tags: c#

I want to have an array in a class that can use by methods of the class itself. I want to evaluate array by a method and read by another one, how can i do this with c#? thanks

```
class Something 
{
    Double[] arrayName = new Double[20]; 
    public void Method() 
    {
        arrayName[index] = value; 
        index++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "evaluate an array by a method"?

Comment: Added the code from your comment to your question (adjusting based on my preference of standards) if I've misrepresented it please adjust.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Foo
{
    private SomeType[] _someArrayField;

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        // you can access the _someArrayField field here
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 even with the underscore ;)

Comment: @AdamRobinson, of course, I prefer prefixing fields with `_` as a convention.

Comment: Right, just a friendly jab; I personally don't like that convention, but it's a matter of taste.

Comment: @AdamRobinson, out of interest what convention do you prefer? `this.myField`?

Comment: In cases where the names could either collide or be ambiguous to the reader, yes. Otherwise, I don't prefix or specify at all.

Comment: And in the case of no collisions? You don't prefix with `this`? How are you able to distinguish between a field and a local variable when you are inside a method if this is the case? Or you don't care for distinguishing between those?

Comment: I don't find it necessary to make an explicit distinction in all cases; in cases where I do, I (of course) use `this.`. I tend to try to keep functions small enough where it's not difficult to determine if the variable in question is a local or parameter vs. an instance or static variable. I also tend to make my fields more formally named, whereas locals I tend to use shorthand (while still keeping a meaningful name for non-trivial variables).

Comment: ow, i'm afraid i did that, my problem is that when i evaluate the array with some method it's value just work inside the method,cannot use other where

Comment: @souphianisus: I'm afraid the language barrier is making that difficult to understand. Could you post some sample code that you've tried and describe the behavior you got vs. what you expected?

Comment: class something { Double[] arrayName = new Double[20]; public void method() { arrayName[index] = value; index++;} I call the method with click and it will add a value to the array...

Comment: @souphianisus: Please edit your question with the code and descriptions; don't post them in comments.

Answer (score 0):

The information you've disclosed about the problem is confusing (likely because of the language barrier), but it is one of two problems:

1. You're trying to access `arrayName` from outside of the context of `Something` (as in from another class), the problem is the access level of `arrayName` (the default access level is `private`). If you need to share the `arrayName` field with another class then you can just prefix it with `public`, like so:

   class Something 
   {
       // Assuming you have `index` defined somewhere
       public Double[] arrayName = new Double[20]; 
       public void Method() 
       {
           arrayName[index] = value; 
           index++;
       }
   }
2. You're trying to assign an array element's value. The code you have should work up to the size of the array, which in your case will be when `index = 20` (or 21 elements). Once the next iteration happens you will encounter an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` because there isn't enough space in the array for the next element.

I'd recommend switching to `List<Double>` which is similar to have a variable length array. Its implementation would look like:

```
class Something 
{
    List<Double> listName = new List<Double>(); 
    public void Method() 
    {
        listName[index] = value; 
        index++;
    }
}
```

But if you can't change the collection type (though I would suggest it if you need this functionality) you can resize your array if `index` is larger than the size of `arrayName`. I can provide an example (or you can find one of the many through a simple search) if this ends up being what you're looking for.